# Proving that REG is reverse-closed against inverse homomorphism

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

prove/disprove

If inverse homomorphism of languages is regular then languages is also regular?

Let $h$ be a homomorphism , if $h^{-1}(L)$ is regular then $L$ is also regular?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Telling us to prove or disprove something isn't a question: it's a homework exercise. The value of homework exercises is that doing them yourself helps you to understand the material. We're happy to help with conceptual questions but we're not going to solve exercises for you.

Answer (score 3):

We can consider a single letter alphabet here, so words over $\{a\}$.

Recall that $h^{-1}(L) = \{ w \mid h(w) \in L \}$.
Consider *any* language $L\subseteq \{a\}^*$ that contains $\varepsilon$.

Let $h(a) = \varepsilon$. Then $h(w)=\varepsilon$ for every word $w$. Thus $h^{-1}(L) = a^*$, which is regular ... for every $L\ni \varepsilon$.